# Output a variable with a SASS mixin

Tags: css, variables, sass, font-face

I am trying to do something along the lines of:

```
@mixin raleway() {
    @include font-face("ralewayregular", font-files("raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.woff", "raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.ttf", "raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.svg"), "raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.eot");
    $raleway: "ralewayregular", Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Then, to use the mixin:

```
@include raleway();

body {
    font: 16px $raleway;
}
```

But, I am getting a `Undefined variable: "$raleway".` error when I try to compile. It looks like the mixin does not make the variable available, does anyone know if this is possible in SASS?

Comment: $raleway is only usable within the mixing like that. I'd setup a new file like _settings.scss and place all global var there. Import the settings in your main document and then you have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

Nico O pretty much says it in his comment, but her's an example. Put the following code near the top of your file:

```
@include font-face("ralewayregular", font-files("raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.woff", "raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.ttf", "raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.svg"), "raleway/raleway-regular-webfont.eot");
$raleway: "ralewayregular", Arial, sans-serif;
```

Then later in the file when you want to use the font:

```
body { font: 16px $raleway; }
```

Check out [this link](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#variable_scope_and_content_blocks) if you want to read up on variable scope in Sass. Hope this helps.